# The best practice for choosing between hibernate vs JDBC or mybatis for only insert in database without any relationship in tables in java

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, orm, mybatis

We have a Web Hook that sends logs to our server with HTTP POST. Suppose the Web Hook call this format:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://our-server-url -d '{"action":"view_order","id":"1001","name":"jack","duration":"59","date":"2020-01-01","order_id":"228"}'
```

The format of logs are JSON. We want to save this JSON data in relational database. Every Log(JSON data) has a field as a the table name (action field) and the rest of the fields are known as table columns. So we already created 10 tables in database because the number of actions are limited to 10 actions. For example Web Hook data is `{'action':'view_order','id':'1001','name':'jack','duration':'59','date':'2020-01-01','order_id':'228'}` so the table name is view_order and rest of the fields are columns.  So after received data, we save them in database according to table name.

The main operation is insert. There is no any extra operation and any relationship between tables. So we want to choose design pattern for insert with best performance.

Comment: I'm kinda not getting your question.

Comment: @akuzminykh Suppose one server send you information in JSON format with http POST and you want to save them into database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The main operation is insert

Without knowing if there are other operations, and if your are seeking to

> insert with best performance

You will get the best performance with JDBC. 
Any framework you add, will add layers that will impact performance. Of course you can tune up this frameworks to be performant with inserts, for example, using batch inserts, but they will not beat the performance of plain JDBC.

Comment: I think the jdbc solution can help me for insert and also bulk insert has a lot of benefits to achieve more performance.